# Remove array items larger than .. number

Tags: javascript

I have an array. I would like to remove any items that surpass the third item leaving 'a', 'b', and 'c' in the array. How do I do this?

```
//my array
var array_name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

//Number of array items to remove
var remove_array_items = 3;

//Desired result
var array_name = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Comment: It's not exactly "Number of array items to remove" if you want to end up with that number. In your example you remove 2 items, not 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
array_name.splice(remove_array_items);
```

to remove all elements *on or after* the one at index: `remove_array_items`

---

```
var array_name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var remove_array_items = 3;

// note this **modifies** the array it is called on
array_name.splice(remove_array_items);

// array_name is now ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: won't the code you've quoted remove everything after 'd' now? It was correct when you had `splice(2)` or should be `array_name.splice(remove_array_items - 1)`

Comment: No. It removes everything from 'd' included.

Comment: yep - just had a look! confused myself from your first answer!

Comment: The `.splice()` method fails in IE8 and lower when you don't provide a second argument.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe - I posted the first answer. Realized the error and corrected it later. You spotted it right. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Truncate the Array by simply setting its `.length` to a lower number.

```
array_name.length = 3;
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/hX29y/